# Using Composer Autoloader with PSR-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm looking at examples, and I cannot get my code to work.

Directory Structure

```
app
    src
        company
            FileExport
                FileExport.php
                FileExportInterface.php
            Validator
    vendor
        ...
```

My `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "1.9.1",
    "ilya/belt": "2.1.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Company\\": "src"}
}
```

Namespace is `Company\FileExport`.

Classes in vendor work fine, but not mine. I've run `composer update` as well.

Comment: Either remove the "company" folder or change the the composer.json to "psr-4": {"Company\\": "src/company"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `autoload` should look like so

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Company\\": "src/company/"}
    }
```